# Elevation/Altitude for track/route

Tags: mapbox-ios

I want to use MapBox to display a GPS track for small planes.
I managed to display the track using annotations, but they are displayed on the terrain, not above.
How can I display a track in altitude (i.e. above the terrain)? Annotations seem to be only in 2D.
Or maybe it is not possible with MapBox?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible with mapbox. At least on iOS.